# Should we have an [automatic-sequences] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The main motivation for this proposal lies in the fact that there are a lot of questions on the site concerning the Thue-Morse and Rudin-Shapiro sequences as well as other related automatic integer sequences which are unfortunately lost within the jungle of questions due to the lack of an appropriate tag.

The study of automatic sequences has dramatically increased since the publication of papers by Allouche and co. in the 1980s and today, there is a lot of interest in this subject. As a quick example, the user *Vladimir Reshetnikov* often posts highly interesting content about the Thue-Morse sequence (see for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239871/products-of-trig-functions-and-the-thue-morse-sequence) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891648/a-nice-formula-for-the-thue-morse-sequence)), which I only recently found by randomly browsing the site.

Personally, I would love to be able to filter for questions concerning such sequences and thus easily find questions and topics related to these fascinating integer sequences.

Comment: Is *automatic-sequences* an established term? I have felt that objects like Thue-Morse sequence are adequately served by tags such as [tag:combinatorics-on-words] and [tag:l-systems]?

Comment: Oops, we don't have a tag on l-systems. But some of the tags related to automata theory and formal languages surely cover this?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AutomaticSequence.html  suggest so

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is: https://www.amazon.com/Automatic-Sequences-Theory-Applications-Generalizations/dp/0521823323, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_sequence